# Capture text between 2 special characters using regex

Tags: java, javascript, regex

I'm trying to determine the best regular expression to capture text from the suite values in the following example strings:

```
Floor: 05; Suite: CPO 5th Floor; Abbrv: CAN-ON-Toronto-CPO5; M9V 1H5
Floor: 05; Suite: CPO 5th Floor; Abbrv: CAN-ON-Toronto-CPO5; M9V 1H5
Floor: 04; Suite: CPO 4th Floor; Abbrv: CAN-ON-Toronto-CPO4; M9V 1H5
Floor: 2; Suite: SOC 2nd Floor; Abbrv: CAN-ON-Scarborough-SOC2; M1H 2X3
```

For example I need to capture the following from the above text:

```
CPO 5th Floor
CPO 5th Floor
CPO 4th Floor
SOC 2nd Floor
```

Basically I need to capture all the text between `Suite:` and `;` excluding the first whitespace.

I am trying to do this in Java and can't come up with a regular expression that would work for multiple scenarios.

Comment: This is pretty straight forward, did you try anything? (It can be done without regex also)

Comment: Are each of these different strings or is this all one string?

Answer (score 2):

```
String str = " Floor: 05; Suite: CPO 5th Floor; Abbrv: CAN-ON-Toronto-CPO5; M9V 1H5 "
           + " Floor: 05; Suite: CPO 5th Floor; Abbrv: CAN-ON-Toronto-CPO5; M9V 1H5 "
           + " Floor: 04; Suite: CPO 4th Floor; Abbrv: CAN-ON-Toronto-CPO4; M9V 1H5 "
           + " Floor: 2; Suite: SOC 2nd Floor; Abbrv: CAN-ON-Scarborough-SOC2; M1H 2X3";

// Pattern: Suite:[ ]*([^;]*);
// Which means:
//   Suite:      - first the string "Suite:"
//   [ ]*        - followed by any amount of whitespace 
//   ([^;]*)     - then a capture group that will contain any
//                 amount of characters except ";"
//   ;           - then the character ;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Suite:[ ]*([^;]*);");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while(matcher.find()){
    String match = matcher.group(1); // first capture group
    System.out.println(match);
}
```

Prints:

```
CPO 5th Floor
CPO 5th Floor
CPO 4th Floor
SOC 2nd Floor
```